# Flutter SnackBarAction cannot set height

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

Cannot set height for snack bar. I need to use snack bar action. But the action label affect snack bar height, when give a long action label text. Does anyone face the same issue ?

long label text affect snackbar height:

[image]

short label text is normal:

[image]

Reproduce code:

```dart
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
  content: const Text('Alamat belum lengkap.',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Lengkapi Alamat',
        onPressed: () {},
    ),
);

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `SnackBar` will be as big as its child.

As an alternative, you can use the [`another_flushbar`](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar) package.

There's also a [`mainButton`](https://pub.dev/documentation/another_flushbar/latest/flushbar/Flushbar/mainButton.html) property as an alternative to your `SnackBarAction`.

[image]

Here's a complete example:

```dart
import 'package:another_flushbar/flushbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: MyApp(),
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Flushbar(
              mainButton: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Lengkapi Alamat',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
                ),
              ),
              message: "Alamat belum lengkap\n very long message to show",
              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            )..show(context);
          },
          child: Text('Show Flushbar'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```